# Asymptotic formula for $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\varphi(k)}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, totient-function

> Is an asymptotic formula of $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\varphi(k)}$$ known ?

The infinite sum $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\varphi(k)}$$ diverges which can be shown by comparing it to the harmonic series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$$

Numerical values :

```
? sum(j=1,10^7,1.0/eulerphi(j))
%44 = 31.26649923752769616067244698051873057166
? sum(j=1,10^8,1.0/eulerphi(j))
%45 = 35.74179524657529982203363898007376015266
?
```

So, the value seems to be roughly $1.94\cdot \ln(n)$. Is this actually true, and if yes, what is known about the constant near $1.94$ ?

Comment: The sum diverges since for primes $\varphi (p)=p-1$, or simply because $\varphi(n)<n$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you, so this part is clear. I will edit my question :) I did not consider that we take the reciprocals, so the sum is actually LARGER than the harmonic sum.

Comment: Downvoting because the formula is literally [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Other_formulae)

Comment: @Wojowu If you consider that to be a reason, OK ...

Comment: So to answer OP's question and save people a click: the constant near 1.94 is exactly equal to $\dfrac{315\zeta(3)}{2\pi^4}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article on the totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Other_formulae), we have $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\varphi(k)}=\frac{315\zeta(3)}{2\pi^4}\left(\log n + \gamma -\sum_{p \in\mathbb{P}}\frac{\log p}{p^2-p+1}\right)+O\left(\frac{(\log n)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{n}\right),$$
so the proportionality constant you found was $\frac{315\zeta(3)}{2\pi^4}$. It was proved in a paper in 1900 by Landau according to [this source](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250127232).